# How can I export a PDF Document in window forms project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, window

For my project there is a document (PDF) "How to Use tool". I would like to give this document who ever using this tool by one button click .

```
private void btnPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Need code Here 
   MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Downloaded", "Download", 
   MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);       
}
```

How can I export a PDF Document in window forms project?

Comment: It depends. Where the file is located? Is it an embedded resource? Is it copied to the output directory? Is it available online in a specific url?

Comment: Your question is confusing, do you want to export a PDF and then open it for the user or download and open a PDF for the user?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start(v=vs.110).aspx) to open the file, eg:

```
private void btnPDF_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Process.Start(@"C:\temp\a.pdf");
 //Need code Here 
 MessageBox.Show("Sucessfully Downloaded", "Download", 
 MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

}
```

If the PDF is online you can use a URL instead of a file path.

If you want the users to save a PDF use a Folder Browser Dialog, eg:

```
using (FolderBrowserDialog dialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
{
    if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        string path = dialog.SelectedPath;
    }
}
```

Comment: As I pointed out in the comment above, his question is confusing, his code sample makes it seem like he wants to download a file and open it for the user but then he asks how to export a PDF, so which is it?